# Get Touch Point in ARCORE

Tags: android, arcore

Im trying to get the realtime touch point when I'm moving my finger across the screen using ARCORE.

I use the following code to get the tap position:

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();

AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
point = anchorNode.getWorldPosition();

});
```

But how can I get the realtime point when Im moving my finger across the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using TapArPlaneListener, use the arSceneView to setup a OnTouchListener and you can use the MotionEvent to get the screen position.
A very simple example would be as follows,

```
arFragment.getArSceneView().setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
        Log.d("Point on screen", motionEvent.getX()+","+motionEvent.getY());
        return true;
    });
```